# how to save data from MultipleChoiceField with checkbox widget in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-orm

I have a Tutor model which has a ManyToManyField to a model called Subjects and I'm trying to render the Tutor form with a MultipleChoiceField and though it is being rendered properly, the values are not being saved in the database, I think I'm doing something wrong in my views.

For Reference, here are the models

```
class Subjects(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class TutorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subjects)
```

And I have populated my Subjects model with some objects

Here is the form,

```
class TutorForm(forms.Form):
      subjectfield = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = ((sub.pk, sub.subject) for sub in Subjects.objects.all()), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

and here is the view,

```
def someview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      form = TutorForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        subjects = form.cleaned_data['subjectfield']
        for sub in subjects:
          form.subject.add(sub)
        form.save()
```

But the values are not getting saved in the database, please help :(

**EDIT**
I finally figured it out with some help from Mohasen Hassani's answer

The form has to be edit as per Mohasen's answer below but the views had to be changed like this,

```
def someview(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TutorForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      t = TutorProfile(user.username=somebody)
      t.save()

      subjects_list = request.POST.getlist('subject')
      counter = 0
      for sub in subjects_list:
        sub_pk = subjects_list.__getitem__(counter)
        sub_entity = Subjects.objects.get(pk=sub_pk) #The model to which we are related
        data.subject.add(sub_entity)
        counter = counter+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your form:

```
class TutorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('subject',)
```

And your view:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

Comment: no luck and the form is being rendered properly, the problem is with saving it and form.cleaned_data['subjectfield'] is returning only one value instead of all the selected ones

Answer (score 0):

Edit your forms to:

```
subjects = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Subjects.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

And in views:
You you have to first create/save a TutorProfile without the subjects, and then supply its subjects field separately. Like this:

```
def someview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      form = TutorForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        t = TutorProfile(user.username=somebody)
        t.save()
        t.subjects = form.cleaned_data['subjects']
```

Comment: Thanks Mohasen for the answer, this renders fine but the values are still not saved in the database :(

Comment: If the code in this answer is incorrect, vote it down and post a new answer.